# OCR, Cropping the letters

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm building a simple OCR, I'm facing a problem of not being to crop the letters after segmenting them using OpenCV. Can anyone help me with a simple way to crop the letters?

Here's the segmenting code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


mser = cv2.MSER_create()
# original image
# -1 loads as-is so if it will be 3 or 4 channel as the original
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg', -1)
# mask defaulting to black for 3-channel and transparent for 4-channel
# (of course replace corners with yours)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
vis = image.copy()

regions = mser.detectRegions(gray)
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions[0]]

channel_count = image.shape[2]  # i.e. 3 or 4 depending on your image
ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, hulls, ignore_mask_color)
# from Masterfool: use cv2.fillConvexPoly if you know it's convex
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(vis, hulls)
cv2.imwrite('img')

#for m in range(len(hulls)):
    #masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(vis, ignore_mask_color)
    # save the result
    #cv2.imwrite('img'+m, masked_image)
```

This results:
[image: after segmenting letters]

I need each letter to be cropped using the same hulls. Any help?

Comment: Please Upload the original image as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't crop and directly save the hulls as you can see them in the example you posted. Or, better, you can crop and paste them in a square/rectangle canvas. But it's not the answer you want for this question.

So, if you have all the text which is computer written, best option to begin is to apply `cv2.findContours()` to the image. There are also other specific tools you can use, but for now (and relatively to this question) use this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image
image = cv2.imread('image.png')

#grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#binary
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('second', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#dilation
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('dilated', img_dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#find contours
im2,ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

    # Getting ROI
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # show ROI
    #cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i),roi)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(0,255,0),2)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    if w > 15 and h > 15:
        cv2.imwrite('roi{}.png'.format(i), roi)

cv2.imshow('marked areas',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can tweak the kernel for more or less wide of the rectangle detection.

[image: res]